# What c++ data types are common to Metal and all other c++ platforms

Tags: android, c++, ios, metal

I am trying to create a backend for a cross platform app that will run in linux, iOS, and Android.

I originally built it with iOS in mind so I was using simd data types for my float2's and my matrixes. However simd is not available to linux or Android so I need something different.

I could of course define my own matrix type and my own float2/3/4 types however I worry I will loose the hardware acceleration ESPECIALLY for matrix multiplication.

I did try seeing if I could make c++ structs that were equivalent to simd types but that caused all sorts of issues. Here were my attempts.

```
struct float2 {
  float x;
  float y;
}; (Was supposed to be equal to simd_float2 and float2 in Metal shading language)

struct float3 {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
}; (Was supposed to be equal to simd_float3 and float3 in Metal shading language)

struct float3x3 {
  float columns[3][3];
}; (Was supposed to be equal to simd_float3x3 and matrix_float3x3 in Metal shading language)

struct Vertex {
  float3 color;
  float2 position;
}; (A struct that is supposed to be common between Engine and Metal Shading language however gets read COMPLETELY wrong when I try to do it this way)

// How can simd types possibly be defined in a way that these aren't equivalent
```

When I started using these structs all havoc broke loose and it was clear that Metal wasn't getting it.

Should I actually be worried about the performance cost of using my own definitions and math for matrix multiplication?

Are there any cross platform libraries that will work defining these structs for both the linux app, my Vulcan Android app, and my Metal iOS app?

Answer (score 4):

The issue (aside from your `struct float3` not having 3 components) is probably due to alignment. For example, as documented in the [Metal Shading Language (MSL) spec](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf), MSL's `float3` (as well as `simd`'s) is not the size of 3 `float`s, it's the size of 4. A struct like this:

```
struct float3 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

does **not** correspond to MSL's `float3`, it corresponds to `packed_float3`. This especially matters if you concatenate data structures, such as making an array of `struct float3` or building a struct that contains fields of type `struct float3` with other fields following that. Your `struct Vertex` exhibits the latter problem. The `position` field is at the wrong offset compared to the same structure in MSL.

You could fix your `struct float3` by adding a fourth field, `float padding;`. You could also fix it using non-standard compiler extensions such as `__attribute__ ((aligned(16)))`:

```
struct float3 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
```

Both GCC and Clang support the `aligned` attribute. I'm sure that MSVC supports a similar feature, but I don't recall what it is off-hand.

Similarly, MSL's `float3x3` is 48 bytes in size and aligned to 16 bytes. It corresponds to `float3[3]` (assuming a correct definition of `float3`).

Comment: Apologies that float3 thing was a typo. What is the MSL spec? Could you explain what a non-standard compiler extension is and where you put it in the struct and how portable it is?

Comment: Thank-you for that insight on the matrix I was wondering why when I looked at that in the debugger there was an extra field.

Comment: You're welcome. See my edit for answers to your questions.

Comment: Thanks again. Odd thing happened. Even when adding the padding element to the float 3 array things didnt quite work out. I actually had to add that alignment bit for whatever reason. The sizeof operator was returning the right thing but something else was going on too? Any ideas?

Comment: Well, an array of four `float`s still has alignment of only 4 bytes. So, depending on how it's allocated and if it's part of a larger structure with preceding fields, the first `float` may not be on a 16-byte boundary.